# Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::labels does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, namespaces, composer-php

I have installed package : Laravel Charts
Everything done as per Docs. but when i am trying to below code in controller. laravel give me error :

```
$chart = new Chart;
$chart->labels(['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']);
$chart->dataset('My dataset', 'line', [1, 2, 3, 4]);
$chart->dataset('My dataset 2', 'line', [4, 3, 2, 1]);
```

error is:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::labels does not exist.

Package details:
[link for doc.](https://charts.erik.cat/render_charts.html#sample-html)
[Link of package](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-charts)

app/Charts/Charts.php code:

```
namespace App\Charts;

use ConsoleTVs\Charts\Classes\Library\Chart;

class Charts extends Chart
{
    /**
     * Initializes the chart.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**I am getting this error:** 
[image]

Comment: It would be great if you added exact name/link to package

Comment: now i added links for package and doc also in question. @MarcinNabiałek

Comment: Can you also please include how your `Chart` model looks like?

Comment: i added `Charts` classed path and code also. @MarcinNabiałek

Comment: Take a look at my answer, especially edit part

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you haven't generated your char using command mentioned in documentation https://charts.erik.cat/create_charts.html#create-a-chart-class

```
php artisan make:chart {Name} {Library?}
```

It seems that generated class should extend Chart class as visible in this stub https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts/blob/master/src/Commands/stubs/chart.stub

If it doesn't extend valid class, it won't have `labels` method and that's why you are getting error.

**EDIT**

If your class looks really like the one you attached, the problem is that class name is `Charts` and you create object of `Chart` and this is probably completely different class so it doesn't contain `labels` method

**EDIT2**

It seems that you are importing invalid namespace. I mean when creating:

```
php artisan make:chart {Name} {Library?}
```

you should probably pass as Library valid type from those: https://charts.erik.cat/supported_libraries.html#chartjs-2-7-1

So for example, instead of:

```
use ConsoleTVs\Charts\Classes\Library\Chart;
```

you should use:

```
use ConsoleTVs\Charts\Classes\C3\Chart;
```

or

```
use ConsoleTVs\Charts\Classes\ChartJs\Chart;
```

you can see available types in documentation and also here: https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts/tree/master/src/Classes

Comment: I have used command as : `php artisan make:chart Charts Library` command and now i added also that class and path of it existed.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right in answered but error changed `Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\Classes\Library\Chart' not found`

Comment: Have you run `composer install` ?

Comment: now i also done `composer install` but, it error is `Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\Classes\Library\Chart' not found`

Comment: I am till facing this error `Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\Classes\Library\Chart' `

Comment: Try to run also `composer dump-autoload` however it should rather work now already

Comment: I have done this `composer dump-autoload` but nothing is changed.

Comment: @KINNARI So the first question is, have you before run `composer require consoletvs/charts:6.*` and followed all steps  described in https://charts.erik.cat/installation.html ?

Comment: I have run this `composer require consoletvs/charts:6.*` before start work.. and i also added serve provider as `ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider::class,`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180950/discussion-between-kinnari-and-marcin-nabialek).